# JDWP through ADB VS JDWP through DDMS

Tags: android, debugging, dalvik, ddms

According to the Android documentation each DVM has a JDWP port to attach (is not exactly the JDWP protocol but implement most of the JDWP features). So you can attach to it using ADB.

And according to the same documentation DDMS provide one JDWP for each DVM and one JDWP base port (8700).

My question is: Pros and Cons of both options.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Every debuggable VM on the device has a connection to ADB.  DDMS talks to ADB to get a list of VMs, and then uses ADB to talk to them.

DDMS listens on a separate TCP port for each VM, so you can "directly" connect to any VM on the device.  Further, as a convenience, it listens on port 8700, and routes any connection there to whichever VM is currently selected in the UI.  You can connect to that port using "debug remote VM" with Eclipse, IntelliJ, jdb, jswat, whatever.

Once connected, the JDWP protocol defines the basic packet format used to communicate (i.e. how packet types and lengths are encoded).  DDMS extends JDWP, defining a new packet format for its purposes.  DDMS messages and debugger messages can be interleaved.

There really aren't two options here.  The debugger talks to DDMS, DDMS talks to ADB, and ADB talks to the VM.  The debugger and VM speak JDWP, and DDMS extends that a bit so it can share the same communication channel.

The original DDMS design doc can be found in the [dalvik docs](http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/debugmon.html).  It's it a bit dated (and, for some reason, formatted in italics) but the essential details haven't changed.