# Is it possible to debug Android apps from command line?

Tags: android, shell, command-line

Device is ready for USB debugging in Developer Options, build.gradle consists

```
debuggable true
```

I have already build & install app by command line, and after:

```
adb shell am start -D ***.package.name/***.ActivityClass
```

I have get "Waiting For Debugger" toast.
So what next?)

Comment: You'll need to use a command line JDWP client, see: [JDWP through ADB VS JDWP through DDMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19926972/295004)